# Why an invisible iframe to logout from Office in a Office phishing?

Tags: phishing, office

In a phishing page for Office account (login mimicking the normal login page and stealing the credentials through a simple ajax request, then navigating to a dummy public google doc), attackers have put an invisible `iframe` with the url

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf?ct=1548343592&rver=64.4.6456.0&lc=1033&id=501392
```

Why would they do that? I don't see the point.

Comment: they log you out to get you to log in.

Comment: What do you mean? Their fake form is not related to the real cookies

Comment: it's about consistency. I'f i'm signed in on another tab, it would raise a flag that i'm being asked to login. If i go back to the other tab, and indeed i'm logged-out, I'm more likely to attempt a login on the fake form.

Comment: Ok yeah, that was my only guess too. It seemed overly subtile to me for such a gross attempt, but yeah. Thanks for sharing